# error creating storage bucket using gsutil

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I do not have billing associated with my google account but when I create a new firebase project I can create a default bucket just by going to storage section on console and pressing get start ([check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4q8g.png))

but when I try to create this default gsutil

```
gsutil mb -p project-id gs://project-id.appspot.com/
```

I got this error

> AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.

is there any way to enable this default storage using gsuitl, code or command without opening the console site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's default bucket works basically by building the storage costs into your Firebase bill. But gsutil is a GCS tool, i.e., you're attempting to use the underlying storage that Firebase uses. To do that, you need to set up billing first.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is billing issue, first setup billing then try to create bucket.

you can use gsutil or use GCP UI to create bucket